# Getting Error: UnsupportedOperationError: mouseMoveTo when trying to perform mouseMove() in IE through protractor

Tags: selenium, protractor, iedriverserver

I am trying to perform mouseMove() action in one of my test scripts in protractor.

It works fine for chrome and older version of Firefox(46), but it fails in IE and latest version of firefox with the below error message:

```
Exception has occurred: Error
UnsupportedOperationError: mouseMoveTo
Build info: version: '3.4.0', revision: 'unknown', time: 'unknown'
System info: host: 'INBEN10185L', ip: '157.237.220.42', os.name: 'Windows 
10', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '10.0', java.version: '1.8.0_141'
Driver info: driver.version: RemoteWebDriver
```

I am using 
Protractor 5.1.2,
selenium-server-standalone-3.4.0.jar,
IEDriverServer3.5.1.exe with IE11.

There has been some discussion about this issue in Firefox earlier:
https://github.com/angular/protractor/issues/4177

But i can't find anything related with IE.

Comment: What was the solution for FF issue?

Comment: @AlexeyR. It's working for an older version of firefox(46) but failing for the new ones which has been discussed in the provided link. Apologies for the confusion, i've updated the question accordingly.